# Devise + RSpec + Capybara : Test that new session created successfully when user logs in

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

In my rails application i am using `Devise` for user authentication.
When a user logs in to the application, `Devise` authenticates that user and creates a session for that particular user.

I need to test that, when a user logs in, a session is created for that user. How do i do that?

In my acceptance test, If i do something like ,

```
    feature 'User logs in' do
      scenario 'with valid email and password' do
        log_in_with 'valid@example.com', 'password'

        expect(page).to have_content('Log out')
      end

      def log_in_with(email, password)
        visit new_user_session_path
        fill_in 'Email', with: email
        fill_in 'Password', with: password
        click_button 'Log in'
      end
    end
```

Still i am not checking that a new session was created for the logged in user. This does not fulfill my requirement as i am not checking if an actual user session was created.

Now, if i use `warden` instead:

```
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    ...
```

i am just saying that login as so and so user and go to next steps like maybe check for a Log Out link or an Edit Profile link, but no check on session creation for the user.

If i do this in controller specs, where i have access to `sign_in` and `sign_out` methods :

```
    describe Devise::SessionsController do

      it "user signed in successfully" do
        logged_user = User.create(:email => "valid@example.com", :password => "12345678")

        sign_in logged_user

        expect(controller.user_session).not_to be nil

      end
    end
```

Here, i have access to `user_session`, `current_user`, `user_signed_in?` methods.
Out of these 3 choices, i opted for `user_session` as it seems to be associated with current user session.
Is this the correct approach? 
Or is there another alternative or direct method available to check that a session is active or was created for a user?
Is there a way to check this scenario in my acceptance test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can access all of your session data using the session hash in Controller specs. You could use it, let's say, to check if the user_id session key has been set after signing in:

`expect(session[:user_id]).to_not be_nil`

And, of course, you can use this to check any session that you might add throughout your application.

If you **really** want to see the session created by Devise, you can access the warden key generated in session:

`expect(session["warden.user.user.key"][0].first).to eql logged_user.id`

It's kind of unnecessary because this is the kind of thing that is already tested in Devise, so testing just if the user is logged in should be enough.

There's a great [post](http://natashatherobot.com/rails-test-omniauth-sessions-controller/) about testing Omniauth controllers that is also a nice guide for testing SessionsController. It uses that old should syntax of RSpec, but it should be understandable =P